# How to force an interactive Bash shell to echo the `read` prompt?

Tags: bash

I don't understand why the the `read` prompt and the answer are not displayed in that use case :

```
bash-4.3.30$ bash -i  <<< 'read -p prompt
answer
echo $REPLY'
```

I would have expected the words "prompt" & "answer" to be displayed. But instead, I obtain that:

```
sylvain@bulbizarre:~$ read -p prompt
sylvain@bulbizarre:~$ echo $REPLY
answer
sylvain@bulbizarre:~$ exit
```

FWIW, this is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I understand out-of-context this can seem stupid. But I really want to feed an *interactive* shell with some commands and observe a behavior very similar to a *real* interactive session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

> -p prompt
>   Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting to read any input. The prompt is displayed **only if input is coming from a terminal**.

When you use a here-doc or here-string, input is coming from a pipe, not a terminal, so the prompt isn't displayed.

You can solve this by using [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to automate execution of the command, instead of redirecting input.

Comment: I spend hours reading docs -- and I just missed that sentence. Thank you for having pointed that out !